# Find all possible matching string and sub-strings from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, typescript

I was trying to find a logic to select the matching string and matching substrings from an array. for ex:

I have a string "3-100" and an array of strings ["3", "3-1", "3-15", "3-",3-10", "3-100"].

when I loop over the array, and compare the strings, I should get true on 2 cases

```
"3" -> true,
"3-1" -> false,
"3-15" -> false,
"3-" -> false,
"3-10" -> false,
"3-100" -> true,
```

How can I achieve this. I tried .includes() which will return true for all cases except "3-15". Looking forward

Adjo

Comment: @anubhava no. the combination 3-100 should only return true :)

Comment: Why is `3` true then?

Comment: I mean 3 and the combination 3-100 should only be true :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regular expression

```js
var arr = ["3", "3-1", "3-15", "3-", "3-10", "3-100"];
var reg = /^3(-100)?$/;
var result = arr.reduce((acc, val, ind) => {
  acc[ind] = reg.test(val);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This helped me to get more clear answer. Thanks Prasun.

Comment: const test = '3.100'.split('-');
      const testRegEx = `^${test[0]}$|^${test[0]}-${test[1]}$`;
      var temp = new RegExp(testRegEx);
      const testResult = temp.test(docNodetoLinkTo.id);

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and look for parts with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var string = "3-100",
    parts = string.split('-').map((_, i, a) => a.slice(0, i + 1).join('-')),
    array = ["3", "3-1", "3-15", "3-", "3-10", "3-100"],
    result = array.map(s => parts.includes(s));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is backward compatible:

```js
var arr = ["3", "3-1", "3-15", "3-", "3-10", "3-100"];
var SearchA = "3";
var SearchB = "100";

for( var i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
  console.log( arr[i] + " = " + ValidateValue(SearchA,SearchB,arr[i]))
}

function ValidateValue( A, B, value ){
  var subarr = value.split("-");
  if( subarr[0] != A ) return false;
  if( subarr.length == 1 ) return true;
  if( subarr[1] != B ) return false;
  return true;
}
```

You can also test it here: [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/kulidixitu/1/edit?js,console)